# Pi4 Screen Res and Overscan

Tags: pi-4

With my new Pi 4, I am having a ton of difficulty getting the display output correct. I have eventually managed to get the resolution correct with a combination of the boot config and the screen configuration tool, however I still have overscan which I cannot seem to stop. I have tried setting `disable_overscan` option to one in the boot config, which didn't work, I have also tried setting the `overscan_left, overscan_right` as well as top and bottom without any luck either.

So far this is my edits/additions to `/boot/config.txt`

```
disable_overscan=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=20
hdmi_drive=2
sdtv_mode=2
```

Normally setting the screen res and overscan would work on my other pi 3. So I am a bit confused as to what's going on.

Comment: If you look down lower in `config.txt`, by chance is your other Pi 3 using the legacy graphics driver (default) and your Pi 4 using fkms (default for Pi 4)? I don't expect those to behave consistently across hdmi_* settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem on my Raspbian Buster Lite (no desktop) / RPi 4 setup. I am running a very minimal setup but the command line was off the bottom of the screen making it impossible to use. I fixed it by logging in blind and running `sudo rpi-update`.
I understand this issue is known and is being worked on at the time of writing so running the above command should come with the usual warnings about this being untested and your results may vary.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Pi 4, when conecting some TVs or monitors via HDMI0 you may need to disable the "new" video driver, which apparently ignores all of these values.

in `/boot/config.txt` you have to comment out this line:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

Also note that "`disable_overscan=1`" should be uncommented, or else it adds an extra 48 pixels around the border, keep that in mind when setting the overscan (left,right,top,bottom) values.